# Why is it necessary to invoke an interrupt twice (hard and then soft) for packet reception?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, interrupt

As known, the Linux kernel receives each frame and subjects it to a four-step process:

- Hardware Reception
- **Hard IRQ:** the NIC asserts the presence of a net frame by interrupting the CPU. This causes the NIC driver to acknowledge the interrupt and schedule the soft IRQ operation.
- **Soft IRQ:** this stage implements the actual frame-receiving process, and is run in softirq context. This means that the stage pre-empts all applications running on the specified CPU, but still allows hard IRQs to be asserted.
- Application receive

Figure 8.1. Network receive path diagram: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-network-packet-reception.html

[image]

But why is it necessary to invoke an interrupt twice: hard and soft?

Why does the CPU when get a hard-irq cause soft-irq directly instead of perform all the work that is now performed in hard-irq and soft-irq?

Comment: If memory serves, the soft irq is merely an address vector.  In other words, it takes a hard irq to perform an actual interrupt.  Without a hard irq, the soft irq amounts to an ordinary subroutine call, albeit with enhanced priority.

Comment: Hard IRQ handler is typicaly too small and too fast to perform a huge task of handling network packet. That's why this task is unloaded to soft IRQ thread.

Comment: @0andriy  Thank you! But why should Hard IRQ be too small, because NIC can't do next work until the CPU completes the interrupt?

Comment: No, it's about CPU. CPU can't do anything else, until IRQ will be served.

Comment: @0andriy So it is done, that Hard-IRQ invoke Soft-IRQ, because Soft-IRQ has lower priority, and during Soft-IRQ this CPU-Core may be interrupted by other Hard-IRQ. I.e. Hard-IRQ does nothing more than causes Soft-IRQ. And Soft-IRQ processes packet in the TCP/IP stack, isn't it?

Comment: Something like that, indeed.